# Why doesn't file/folder encryption work the way I imagine it should? Can I have the UX I want? Tell me what's wrong with this idea

Tags: encryption, gnupg, file-encryption, user-interface, usability

I have been looking around at various encryption schemes, and I haven't found anything exactly like what I want in terms of user experience.

If what I want isn't a thing, I assume it's been thought of, but other approaches won out. So can someone help me understand what would be wrong with a security model that works like this?

1. A utility that interfaces with my GUI and terminal such that a GPG-encrypted archive is displayed as a special kind of folder.
2. I can navigate into this archive/fake folder using `ls` or open files/paths within it like any other directory, except that I need to enter the password when opening a file or changing directory.
3. Decryption happens either in memory or in a root-only temporary directory that isn't synced, such that the decrypted data is never synced to the cloud.
4. If the system configurations and stuff that underlie the fake folder/archive thingy are lost, it can simply be decrypted like any normal GPG-encrypted archive. Likewise, GPG archives copied onto a system where this is set up will behave like password-protected folders.
5. What would be even nicer would be to tie this to a hardware key so that I can `ls` and open files in the encrypted "folder" and authenticate by just touching the key.

Does this exist? If not, is there a reason why it is a bad or impractical security model?

And does anything like this have to be a whole filesystem like EncFS? Can't it just be an extension of the file browser that transparently handles unarchiving and shows the resulting folder/files?

Comment: #5 jumps out at me... if that hardware key goes bad seems like you'll need a fallback option.  The rest is just password protection or encryption per folder.  I'm sure there's plenty of options for that... a quick google brought up "ecryptfs" for Linux.  Windows has it's own built-in options.

Comment: @pcalkins EncFS isn't using GPG, so I was thinking that would be less portable (same for Windows encryption). All I want is to interact with GPG-encrypted archives as if they are folders. As far as I can tell, what I am thinking of is just a convenient front-end for GPG.

Comment: *"Can't it just be an extension of the file browser that transparently handles unarchiving and shows the resulting folder/files?"* - access to files by the application or by `ls` is not done through the file browser. Instead both applications, ls and file browser just access the OS. Encryption is also not done by decrypting the whole file and saving it (in plain) somewhere for the application, since this would be unsafe. Instead the parts of the file which need to be worked with are transparently decrypted/encrypted by the OS or file system driver.

Comment: And gpg is not a container format well suited for transparent encryption/decryption/modification of parts of files. In general I find this question more like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). It is not clear what problem X you want to solve, but your solution Y is to use GPG, but more comfortable. Then you ask how to realize Y. It might be better to go a step back and show the initial problem X you want to solve, instead of only your incomplete attempt Y.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I suppose it doesn't need to be GPG, but I do want it to something where the encrypted files/folders can be decrypted independent of the system I am imagining. For example my understanding is that EncFS encrypted folders can't be decrypted without installing EncFS and mounting the encrypted folder.

Comment: @Stonecraft: GPG encrypted files also cannot be decrypted without having GPG (or similar) installed. And EncFS does not depend on the specific system, i.e. the same volume can be mounted on other systems - similar to how GPG encrypted data do not depend on the system were they were created.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich but there are many programs one can choose from to decrypt a GPG/Blowfish/etc encrypted file, and those utilities are more standard. Asking people to decrypt a file I shared with them isn't as big an ask as having them mount an unfamiliar filesystem.

Comment: @Stonecraft: *"Asking people to decrypt a file I shared with them"* - This use case is only relevant if you share the originally encrypted file while also sharing your private password for this file - which sounds like a very bad idea to me. Usually one would encrypt the file for others with a password specific for the purpose. But again - none of these requirements are part of your question, where you only present your attempted solution Y instead of the real problem X you have.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I would simply have one password that I use for all files that I expect to keep private and unique passwords for shared files. What I want is to create encrypted directories on a case-by-case basis, but interact with them without explicitly decrypting to a new file.